# Navigating Screen with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am working on an app in Jetpack and I want to traverse from one compose screen to another. I have a login compose and I want whenever the button from the login compose is clicked to go to the next compose. I have my data stored in a View Model also, can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3Wo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4t6F.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsiYV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFlWE.png)

Comment: refer my complete blog on navigation : https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-navigation-best-practices-beginners-239794217b61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup your appnavigation like the example below

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation() {
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController, startDestination = "login") {
    composable("login") {
        LoginScreen(
            viewModel = viewModel,
            onLoginClicked = {
                // Navigate to the next screen
                navController.navigate("nextScreen")
            }
        )
    }
    composable("nextScreen") {
        NextScreen()
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your mainactivity you can have your appnavigation called in the setcontent like the below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        AppNavigation()
    }
  }
}
```

2. You can use a nav library like this one i always use [dcompose-navigation](https://github.com/deonwaju/dcompose-navigator)

and it gives you the ease to use a function like the below anywhere clickable in your code.

```
fun navigateToExample(navController: NavController) {
  val data = // Your optional data
  navigateTo(navController, "key", "destinationRoute", data)
}
```